# How to declare that primary key is both one-to-one field?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

If I write this way

```
@Id
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="Id")
private Region region;
```

it says

```
Composite-id class must implement Serializable: ....InPopulation
```

I don't want it be composite key, I just want `id` replaced by `Region` of appropriate id.

Comment: could you explain a more bit of your use case and whats actually the  entities having `OneToOne` relations. And of course the error stackTrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `MapsId` annotation for that (i have assumed how the @Id is declared):

```
@Id
private Long id;

@JoinColumn(name = "Id")
@OneToOne
@MapsId
private Region region;
```